# How to update text and simultaneously toggle a new inline style in draft js?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

When I click on a particular button a `handleMouseDown` functions triggers on an `onMouseDown` event:

```
handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.handleMouseDown(this.props.symbol);
}
```

which triggers a `handleMouseDown` function of the actual editor class which looks like this:

```
handleMouseDown(symbol) {
    let newState = this.insertText(symbol);
        
    this.setState({ editorState: newState }); // First action
    this.toggleInlineStyle("SUBSCRIPT"); // Second action
}
```

The problem is that I can only do one of the actions at once - if I comment out the text insertion, the subscript inline style is toggled, if I comment out the inline style toggling the new text is inserted, however if I leave it like this, the symbol doesn't get inserted while the inline style changes and finally, if I change the order, the symbol gets inserted but the inline style doesn't change. How do I do both of those actions properly at once?

The insertText function:

```
insertText(characterToInsert) {
    let editorState = this.state.editorState;

    const currentContent = editorState.getCurrentContent(),
        currentSelection = editorState.getSelection();

    let newContent = Modifier.replaceText(
        currentContent,
        currentSelection,
        characterToInsert
    );

    let newEditorState = EditorState.push(editorState, newContent, 'insert-characters');

    return newEditorState;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add an inline style into the new editor state by using: `EditorState.setInlineStyleOverride`.

So it would look like this:

```
handleMouseDown(symbol) {
    let newState = this.insertText(symbol);
    EditorState.setInlineStyleOverride(newState, OrderedSet.of('SUBSCRIPT'));
        
    this.setState({ editorState: newState });
}
```